# Why does a *.sh script executed on a remote machine sometimes return only partial output?

Tags: bash, ssh, pipe, sh, cat

I run a command `cat getStorage.sh | ssh -T remoteHost >> storageLog.csv`.

`getStorage.sh` looks like this:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
dateTime=$(date)
echo -n $dateTime,
df -h /directory/ | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $2","$3 }'
```

Normally this returns `storageLog.csv` that looks like this:

```
Tue Sep 7 14:44:59 EDT 2021,275G,500G
```

However, sometimes (sporadically), it returns only partial output like this:

```
Tue Sep 7 14:54:59 EDT 2021,
```

What might cause this?

Comment: Instead of `echo`, you could just do `date | tr \\n ,`

Comment: The entire script could be written as `df -h /dir | awk 'END{system("date | tr \\\\n ,"); print $2, $3}' OFS=,`  By reducing the number of processes, you reduce the chance of data being truncated when one of the processes terminates from an unexpected signal. It doesn't really fix the problem, but this will give you zero output occasionally instead of partial output.

Comment: @WilliamPursell downstream scripts may better tolerate a blank line better than a partial line; great suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure `df -h /directory/` is printing something?

Comment: @Barmar yes, it generally works.

Comment: Could there sometimes be an extra blank line at the end?

Comment: In particular if you have any networked filesystems, `df` can be slow to run. So if the `echo "$dateTime"` happened and `df` hasn't finished yet, well, there's your problem.

Comment: BTW, if you only need to support new versions of bash (starting with 4.3 or 4.4, IIRC), you can use `printf -v date ''%(%c)T' -1` as a faster replacement for `date=$(date)`. Replace `%c` with any other `strftime`-style string describing the date format you want.

Comment: (also, GNU awk [has its own strftime equivalent](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html), so you shouldn't really need `date` regardless).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the line to either be written as a whole or not written at all, don't break up your writes; do only one `echo` that writes the output all at once, after telling the script to exit if any of `df`, `tail` or `awk` report failure.

This both avoids race conditions where something tries to read from the file while it's half-written, and also avoids error cases where writing the date succeeds but something else fails before the `df` pipeline has happened.

Each `write()` syscall is atomic (sorta -- they *can* write fewer bytes than requested, but this generally only happens with sockets and other objects "subject to flow control", to quote the MacOS man page for `write`; for regular files, when the content being written is less than a page, a write generally goes through as a whole or not at all -- so you reduce room for errors when you write your content a chunk at a time, *especially* when your file is opened in `O_APPEND` mode).

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o pipefail # tell bash to call a whole pipeline a failure if any part fails

dateTime=$(date) || exit
dfData=$(df -h /directory/ | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $2","$3 }') || exit
echo "$dateTime,$dfData"
```